# reorder array starting at given position, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to do one thing that is easy in python using slice lists,
but I can't find a easy way to do that in c++.

I need to reorder a array to start at a given element like:
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
reordered array to start at element 3:
{3,4,5,1,2}

this is the way I found to do that, but it seems to be a bit overkill:

```
void Graph::reorder(int x, MIntArray &currentArray) 
{
    MIntArray reorderedIndices;
    int index;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<currentArray.length();i++){if(currentArray[i]==x){index=i;}} // get the index
    for (unsigned int i=index; i<currentArray.length();i++){reorderedIndices.append(currentArray[i]);} // zero to index
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<index;i++){reorderedIndices.append(currentArray[i]);} // index to last
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<currentArray.length();i++){currentArray.set(reorderedIndices[i],i);} // transfer
}
```

any help would be much appreciated!!

thanks

luiz

Comment: What library is MIntArray from?  The details of that class are relevant to developing a better solution.  Also you haven't explicitly stated a question.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`std::rotate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) method to do this reordering. Supply the beginning of the array as the first parameter, the end of the array (i.e. `array+length`) as the last parameter, and the "midpoint" as the second parameter. Midpoint defines the index of the element to be moved to the initial position.

```
int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
rotate(x, x+2, x+5);
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++)
    cout << x[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/XEldk8) `3 4 5 1 2`

Comment: @user1822451 You are welcome! If this answers your question, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the outline of check mark next to it. This would indicate to others that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.